# Enable Unicode Syntax in cabal

Tags: haskell, unicode, cabal

I want to enabled Unicode syntax(UnicodeSyntax extension, base-unicode-symbols package and the containers-unicode-symbols). I don't want to enable per file, that is far too tedious.
How do I enable all three in this .cabal file?

https://github.com/styx/Raincat/blob/master/Raincat.cabal

This is 2013 and I want to use Unicode, not ASCII.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to your `extensions` field:

```
extensions: UnicodeSyntax
```

in your .cabal file. and also add dependencies on those libraries as well:

```
build-depends: base-unicode-symbols
```

etc.

Note that althought it is indeed 2013, that doesn't mean you should be using a non-standard Prelude -- these packages have relatively few users, so you risk making your code more obscure.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. It's not surprising there are few users, it's a pain in the neck to make it work